# I need help in structure of "Have to" within Continuous Tenses

Tags: syntactic-analysis

As I know we can use "Have to" in Simple and Perfect Tenses. Can we use it in Continuous tenses? If I am not wrong, the following sentences are in Present Continuous Tense with "Have to" Structure in it:

She has to be working with me.
She is not have to be working with me.